# Angular: Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y' on custom directive

Tags: angular

I'm doing a little interface for a chat app, for my testing obout animations, etc, I try to make a component reload when adding a new user, i made a directive that is observing a variable and if it changes the component update and reload.

This is my home.component.ts

```
 users: User[] = [
    {name: 'Mike', status: 'online'},
    {name: 'Karla', status: 'away'},
  ]

 newUser:User;

 onEnter(buscar:string){ //add to friend list
    console.log(buscar)
    this.newUser = {name : buscar , status: 'online'}
    this.users.push(this.newUser)
    var input = document.getElementById('buscar') as HTMLInputElement;
    input.value = '';
    console.log(this.users)
  }
```

This is my home.component.html, newUser is the variable that I want to listen, and this scroll view to update, it has an input that open `onEnter()` funtion that is above

```
<div class="friends" *appReloading="newUser">
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport appendOnly itemSize="20" class="example-viewport" >
            <div *cdkVirtualFor="let user of users" class="example-item">
              <div *ngIf="user.status === 'online'">
                 <i class="fa-solid fa-circle" style="color: #56e184;"></i>
                 <button (click)="openChat(user.name)">{{user.name}}</button>
              </div>

              <div *ngIf="user.status === 'away'">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle" style="color: #e1df56;"></i>
                <button (click)="openChat(user.name)">{{user.name}}</button>
             </div>

             <div *ngIf="user.status === 'offline'">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-circle" style="color: #e15656;"></i>
              <button (click)="openChat(user.name)">{{user.name}}</button>
           </div>

            </div>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

And finally this is my directive

```
@Input() newUser : any;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainerRef : ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef)
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges):void{

    if(changes['newUser']){
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
    }
  }
```

I try to keep variable names so I dont get lost.

I try to fix this using the advice is giving me but my directive is declarated and when i try to allow properties to the ngModule everithing gets an error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What module declares your `HomeComponent`? Does it import the module that declares your `ReloadingDirective`?

Comment: HomeComponent and ReloadingDirective both are declared in app.module.ts, should I be declaring the directive in the HomeComponent?